# Remove quote marks from excel cells using node xlsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, playwright, node-xlsx

I'm using [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx) to try and write a simple data structure to a new Excel file.  When it gets written, I see no quotation marks around the cell data yet when I upload the file into a browser using automation, it gets rejected because quote marks have been added to all the string values. I'm not clear why this is happening

The code:

```
export async function createExcelFile(testInfo, fileType, 
adaptationId) {
const [tomorrow, nextMonth] = await getDatesForFiles();

 const data = [
    {
        'storeNumber': 33228,
        'adaptationId': parseInt(adaptationId),
        'effectiveFrom': tomorrow.replaceAll('"', ''),
        'effectiveTo': nextMonth.replaceAll('"', '')
    }
];
// @ts-ignore
const buffer = xlsx.build([{name: "Sheet One", data: data}], { 
cellDates: false });

//write the buffer to a file in a temp folder
const tempFileName = uuid.v4() + '.xlsx';
const tempFilePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src' ,'test-data', 
'temp-files', tempFileName);
    fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, buffer);

    return [tempFileName, buffer];
}
```

All values except for the number `33228` are affected so looks like this is a lead - how can I prevent this behaviour? Using `replace()` with a regex seems to have no effect.

I am using Playwright's [fileChooser](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-filechooser) function to do the upload and I wonder if the error lies here?

```
await fileChooser.setFiles({
   name:fileName,
   mimeType:'application/vnd.ms-excel',
   buffer: Buffer.from(buffer)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'` - which is the .xlsx one.

`application/vnd.ms-excel` is .xls, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/vsofficedeveloper/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2)

Comment: I have and sadly this doesn't work.  When I do a toString() on the buffer I get output like this: <c r="D1" t="str"><v>EffectiveTo</v></c> where I think the t="str" determines the String, but still lost as to how to remove the double quotes